# Utilizar token de api rest en una variable de session

Tags: php, api, tokens, refreshtoken

Que tal estimados tengo una consulta como puedo guardar el token en una variable de session y poder utilizarlo para hacer peticiones en el api

este es el codigo que me permite generar el token

```
    <?php
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'veronica';
$basic_auth ='dmVyb25pY2E6dmVyb25pY2E=';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8080/veronica/oauth/token?');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
  'username' => ''.$username.'',
  'password' => ''.$password .'',
  'grant_type' => 'password'
)));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
  'Accept: application/json',
'Authorization: Basic '.$basic_auth.''

]);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;



?>
```

y esto es lo que da de resultado

```
{"access_token":"2276d11e-0735-485b-9eb0-7ba8a087bb6e","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"9ace89ea-ce16-486c-b6d5-44160b24774e","expires_in":111,"scope":"read write"}
```

lo que quiero es donde dice access_token quiero almacenar el resultado en una varibale de session

Comment: No queda claro si lo que no podes hacer es obtener el valor `access_token` o guardar dicha info en una variable de sesión o ambos.

Comment: quiero guardarla en una variable de session

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [este tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-use-sessions-and-session-variables-in-php--cms-31839)